# Is Romans 11:11 an allusion to Isaiah 8:14?

Tags: romans, isaiah

Romans 11:11 NKJV

> 11 I say then, have they ***stumbled*** that they should fall? Certainly not! But through their fall, to  provoke them to jealousy, salvation has come to the Gentiles.

Isaiah 8:14 NKJV

> 14 He will be as a sanctuary,  But a stone of ***stumbling*** and a rock of offense  To both the houses of Israel,  As a trap and a snare to the inhabitants of Jerusalem.

Been going through these texts and felt that Paul could be referring to the rejection of Christ by the Jews as the reason for their stumbling upon the  rock.I'm not sure about this interpretation.

Could there be some allusion in the above texts?

Answer (score 2):

The second half of the verse is definitely an allusion to Deuteronomy 32:21 the same way that Romans 10:19 is a direct quote from Deuteronomy 32:21.

But the stumbling-stone and the rock of offense is made reference to in plenty of the prophets, namely Isaiah 8:14 which is referred to by both Paul and Peter. As well as referred to and quoted by Jesus. In Matthew 21:42 Jesus is quoting from Psalm 118:22-23.

The image of a stone is used in reference to the Messiah in Isaiah 28:16, Daniel 2:34, and in other places.

There is a good chance that the stumbling Paul is referring to in Romans 11:11 is to the stumbling at this stone.

> 1 Corinthians1:23
>   But we preach Christ crucified, unto the Jews a stumblingblock, and unto the Greeks foolishness;